# PC takes around 2 minutes to react to shutdown command

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown

So I just upgraded my PC to Windows 8.1 from Windows 7. It all works like a charm. The only thing that's really buggy is if I press the shutdown logo. It takes up to two minutes to finally display the *Shutting Down* message with the logo. I can use my PC freely up to the point it shows the spinning logo.

Shutting down takes another 5 minutes. Booting my PC takes 1 minute total.

**Steps I've taken to troubleshoot on my own:**

1. Update drivers
2. Ran `bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes`
3. Turn off fast start up
4. Changed **WaitToKillServiceTimeout** to `2000`
5. **ClearPageFileAtShutdown** was set to `0` so I didn't change that

**System Specs:**

- **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2300 CPU** @ 2.80GHz; 4 Cores; CPU ID BFEBFBFF000206A7 Family 06 Model 2A Stepping 7 Revision
- **NVIDIA GeForce GT 440** (Manufacturer NVIDIA); Driver Version 9.18.13.4475; Dedicated Memory 1.4 GB; Total Memory 3.9 GB
- **Memory 8.2 GB**
- **Windows 8.1 Professional Edition** (build 9200), 64-bit Service Pack 0
- **American Megatrends Inc. BIOS**; Date: 04/19/11 13:43:56; Ver: 04.06.04 Version P01-A3

Comment: Your post is rather unreadable, please improve it: use [formatting](https://superuser.com/help/formatting), look at the preview before posting, capitalize 'I's and appropriate terms (Windows, PC). Use the [edit] button.

Comment: The reason could be due to many factors while a windows 8 machine shutting down. Application currently running, Processes running in the background, Windows Updates, Not enough paging files, and a hardware issue. Please refer the following url to check your case: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-taking-forever-shut-try/

Comment: So I did all that beside the error-cheking of my hard disk.(runnign it right now)
But all of that has no effect. @vembutech

Comment: Can you check whether you are having any Desktop background theme, it will also make delay in system shutdown.

Comment: It's just the Default Windows theme @vembutech

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific ? I'm not that good. @Ramhound

Comment: Just use `msconfig` without knowing what your not good with I can't really help.  **I likely won't be back.**

Comment: okay so did that. I noticed that it restart instanlly after the program asked to do it. But after the first boot-up with the system set to basic boot-up it still takes 2 min to react.

Also i noticed that if i did a defrag. with an other tool than the basic windows defrag. ans select "shutdown after defragmentaion" the shutdown is instant @Ramhound

Comment: Ok I fixed it kinda ....

Made an script with shutdown -p

Reacts faster but still takes a long time to shutdown.
But it's something
Thaks for all the help @Ramhound

Comment: and @vembutech 
If i find sometthing better i will post it here

Answer (score -1):

Create a batch script with the following:

```
shutdown -p
```